# Understanding where does the second (stochastic) attractor of the system come from.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, bifurcation, basins-of-attraction

I am currently reading a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0960077919300128?via%3Dihub), studying the population dynamics in 3-dimensional Lotka-Volterra model with the following interaction change descriptive system:
$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \dot x = ax - 0.06x^2-\Large\frac{xy}{x+10}\normalsize,\\
        \dot y = -y + \Large\frac{2xy}{x+10}\normalsize-\Large\frac{0.405\cdot yz}{y+10}\normalsize,\\
        \dot z = 0.038z^2 -\Large\frac{z^2}{y+20}\normalsize.\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}\tag{1}
$$

Where $a$ is the variable parameter, for different values of which the model's behavior is studied.

In the paper, authors claim, that the respective non-degenerate (biologically meaningfull if $a > 0.9158$) equlibria for $(1)$ is $M_3(\bar x_3, \bar y_3, \bar z_3)$, where $\bar x_3 = \frac{a}{0.12}-5+\frac{\sqrt{(a+0.6)^2-1.52}}{0.12},~\bar y_3 = 6.31579,~\bar z_3 = -40.3 + 80.6\frac{\bar x_3}{\bar x_3 + 10}.$

Now, the problem is that further in the paper, authors consider a case, when $(1)$ posesses coexisting limit-1 cycle (red) and two-band chaotic attractor (blue).
[image: Fig.1 in-paper description of attractors of (1)]

But the case is, I understnad what the red curve is, that is just basically the set of solutions of the system $(1)$, plotted not against the time variable, but against each other $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. I even managed to get the "red" curve by myself, by solving $(1)$ for $a=1.803$ in python, using `scipy.integrate.odeint`:
[image: My solution of (1)]

But then, I completely fail to understand, where does the "blue" attractor come from, and there is no any further information in the paper  about where it comes from as well, rather the blue attractor is just called "attractor of a Feigenbaum's tree".

If anyone would be so kind to explain me, where the "blue" attractor here comes from, that would be great!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the time $T$ of the period of the red attractor? Have you tried selecting random initial points in, say, $[25,30]\times[0,10]\times[0,20]$, integrate them silently over $5T$ and then check if close to the red curve, else plot them over several periods. One could define a "period start" by the event of crossing the $x=15$ plane downwards. `solve_ivp` provides a usable event mechanism for that.

Comment: ((Btw., if you use `$$\left\{\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\right.\tag{1}$$`, you get the formulas in display mode without having to force the font sizes.))

Comment: I meant to write $z=15$ as event. But a better separation of the periodic and strange attractor is to be obtained by the event $y=24$, again downwards. I get both attractors by drawing 10 random points from the mentioned box.

Comment: @LutzLehmann excuse me, I got a bit lost, what do you mean by saying: "write $z=15$", as an event? And concerning the emergence of the strange attractor, can you, please, specify how do you get them both here? Just I'm kind of a newbie in such type of tasks, and hence barely understand how to write the corresponding code to "draw" points for the blue attractor :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern ODE solver packages have events and actions. Events test for some condition, actions change state, parameters or event the ODE function at such points. The scipy solver `solve_ivp` only implements events and the hard-coded actions to register the event points (always) and to terminate the integration (by a flag).

ODE function and event can be implemented as

```
def model(t,u,a):
    x,y,z = u
    dx = x*(a - 0.06*x - y/(x+10))
    dy = y*(-1+2*x/(x+10)-0.405*z/(y+10))
    dz = z*z*(0.038-1/(y+20))
    return dx,dy,dz

a=1.803

u0 = [29.9,0.2,15.0]

def event(t,u,a): return u[1]-24
event.direction = -1

T = 40
res = solve_ivp(model,(0,10*T),u0, args=(a,), events=event, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-9)
res = solve_ivp(model,(0,20*T),res.y_events[0][-1], args=(a,), events=event, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-9)

print(res.t_events[0])
```

As we are looking for stable attractors, it makes sense to let the solver run for some time to get close to an attractor. The period is about $T=40$, letting it run for 20 periods may seem excessive, 10 are also sufficient.

Now loop through some random initial points from $[25,30]×[0,10]×[0,20]$ and plot the stabilized trajectories, and the event locations in the x-z-plane. One finds that the events lie on a straight line, thus also draw the path of the $x$ coordinate in a successor map.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4.5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 3)
ax = [ fig.add_subplot(gs[k, 2]) for k in [0,1]]
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, :2])
for k in range(10):
    u0 = np.random.uniform(size=3)*np.array([5,10,20])+np.array([25,0,0])
    res = solve_ivp(model,(0,10*T),u0, args=(a,), events=event, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-9)
    res = solve_ivp(model,(0,10*T),res.y_events[0][-1], args=(a,), events=event, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-9)
    ax3.plot(res.y[0],res.y[2], lw=0.8)
    ax[0].plot(res.y_events[0][:,0],res.y_events[0][:,2],'-+', lw=0.5)
    ax[1].plot(res.y_events[0][:-1,0],res.y_events[0][1:,0],'-+', lw=0.5)
for ak in [ax3,*ax]: ak.grid(); 
ax3.set_xlabel("$x$"); ax3.set_ylabel("$z$")
ax[0].set_xlabel("$x_E$"); ax[0].set_ylabel("$z_E$")
ax[1].set_xlabel("$x_E[k]$"); ax[1].set_ylabel("$x_E[k+1]$")
plt.show()
```

In the resulting plot the stable loop is well-isolated, the point in the lower left corners, and the alternating  connection of the two loops of the chaotic attractor is also visible in the second and last plot.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's so explicit and precise explanation! Thank you so much!

Comment: Now, by what you have explained, I start to understand the concept of the stochastic attractor itself much better, thank you once again!

Comment: Great answer also in my opinion, with the explicit code reported

Comment: May I ask some clarifications about the event chosen to start plotting? it should be when it crosses the plane y=24 right? How did you choose to track that event?

Comment: Further, could you also comment a bit (if you like) on the straight line you find and why did you choose to make that successor plot? Thanks for any insight :)

Comment: @Thomas : As noted in the other comments, I first used $z=15$, but the curves are rather close there. The plot in the x-y-plane then showed that the section at around $y=25$ was more spread-out, but still close and parallel. From the first 3D plot one can see that any section transversal to the bottom arc would be suitable.

Comment: @Thomas : The straight line is just a curiosity, it could be a consequence of the bifurcation process (varying $a$), or some structure of the system. The successor map is just an illustration of the internal structure, cycles, if there were any, would show up there. So we see the alternating clusters. Zooming in via $2k\to 2k+2$ could show structure, order or chaos, inside a cluster. Again, under variation of $a$ it can be expected that windows with periodic orbits occur where the chaos resolves into a finite cycle.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot for the clarifications !